# Multiple development provision profile selection

Tags: ios4, ios-provisioning

I am managing two different Apple Dev accounts on my machine. I successfully installed development provision profiles on my machine. Even install the app on device which worked perfectly.

Now since 2 dev provision profiles are installed, How can I point out to a particular one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ensure there is only one active provisioning profile when your codesign execution occurs. Provisioning profiles are stored in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles. A simple way to do this would be:

1. remove the folder listed above
2. do "open file.mobileprovision" from the shell
3. execute your xcodebuild command. This will ensure you have the correct profile active.

Don't forget to back up your existing provisioning profiles before removing the folder...

You can also manually set the active profile in the build tab of your target's Get Info dialog in Xcode.